# Pentaho Wirting to Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am using Pentaho to query an Oracle database. My sql and query has worked fine and returned results. However when I add the step of Microsoft Excel Output, it does not output any data that happens to be a time stamp.

When I go to the step and click into the Fields tab, I see all my fields, and their type set properly. For example, I have an Open_Time which returns a date and time stamp: 01/01/17 12:59:01 in the preview, but when the output and file are created the column is completely blank.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't prefer Excel file output step. Try using `Text File Output` with `xls` extension and don't forget to specify the `format`. I just tested it and worked for me.

Comment: that works as it outputs everything, which is what I wanted. however when I open it in excel all data is on the same row, no columns except column A are created. So you have column A1 which has all the headers in it. Then A2 is the first row of data, etc. I am pulling around 20,000 rows of data and we need the columns to be there with data in each.

Comment: Excel uses the Windows list separator character from your locale, a semicolon where I come from.  You must configure Text-File-Output to use that character instead of the default (comma).  Also, no need to lie about the file type - Excel will happily open files with extension csv, too.